# Does an instance method get loaded into memory per object or per class?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, static

If I have an object `O` with a gigantic method `f()`, and I load 10000 examples of `O` into memory. Are 10000 examples of `f()` loaded into memory as well? If so, does that mean that I would save memory by making this function static if possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instance Methods are loaded in to Method Area in JVM. it is loaded once , but there will be many stack  for every call u make to f() , to keep track of there own local variable values.

Comment: Let you know if you're wrong?  If you're not sure, don't answer the question.

Comment: It's important to note that the stack space for the method is only used DURING A CALL TO IT. There are not 10,000 pieces of stack in use at any time just because you have 10,000 instances created.

Comment: @DJClayworth  yes that is right. when a method is completed , stack space is removed.how about when doing recursion ?

Comment: I might be wrong, but aren't classes loaded once per classloader chain, rather than once per JVM? So should methods: once per classloader chain

Answer (score 6):

No. There is only one instance of the method loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Instance method is just a template and is defined in a class (not in every instance). You wouldn't save memory by making it static.

Answer (score 2):

No. Methods are not part of instances; they're part of classes. There would be no point in repeating the code for each instance (because it would never vary) so the implementation is, quite simply, smarter than that.